# Sorting a list of Router Interface

Tags: java, sorting

have list which contains router interface as: -

```
GigabitEthernet 1/0, GigabitEthernet 1/1,GigabitEthernet 1/11, GigabitEthernet 1/10, GigabitEthernet 1/3`
```

Now I am applying `Collection.sort(list)` to sort, but it causes a problem it sorts something like this: -

```
GigabitEthernet 1/0, GigabitEthernet 1/1, GigabitEthernet 1/10, GigabitEthernet 1/11, GigabitEthernet 1/3`
```

But in our case it should sort it like this: -

```
GigabitEthernet 1/0, GigabitEthernet 1/1, GigabitEthernet 1/3, GigabitEthernet 1/10, GigabitEthernet 1/11`
```

How can I achieve this type of sorting in Java.

Comment: Supply an appropriate comparator to `Collections.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string into a `class`, and sort a List of that `class` using an appropriate `Comparator`.

Something like

```
class GigabitEthernet{
    public int num; //up/down?
    public int denom;
    public GigabitEthernet(String str); // parse
    public String toString(); //regenerate string
}
```

This should make the comparator cleaner

Comment: When you say `class`, do you mean a custom class to hold the strings, or something else?

Comment: @RandallCook Have updated my answer, Idea is to parse into a data structure which can then be compared easily and cleanly

Comment: I like it. I believe I would code it similarly. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own comparator instance and invoke `sort` method with comparator: http://goo.gl/Zz13w

Your comparator will control the sorting order.

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for the response but i think everybody has given me the idea of sort with implementing comparator. I am aware of this api but my real questions was what how would the implementation look like in this case for comparator. Please respond

Comment: Extract substrings from the strings involved in comparison, then convert strings to numbers and compare them. To extract substrings, use substring() method of String class. To convert string to number (integer), use Integer.parseInt() method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method from Collections which takes a comparator as a second argument (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and implements for example an anonymous comparator class which do the right compare for your sort